# Get Data On two Column Based from one Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have table something like this

```
ID|Incident_ID|Emp_No|Status   |
__|___________|______|_________|
1 | 1         |1001  |Approved |
2 | 1         |1002  |Approved |
3 | 2         |1003  |Approved |
4 | 2         |1004  |Pending  |
5 | 3         |1005  |Pending  |
6 | 3         |1006  |Pending  |
```

Now I want output On Incident_ID and Status column-based if all Status is Approved for any particular incident_ID then should be visible here 1 should be visible among three incident_ID because all status are approved for incident_ID =1

**My Query:**

```
select Incident_ID, Status from tbl_Investigation_Review where Status = 'Approved' group by Incident_ID, Status
```

But it's Displaying both incident_ID Please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to filter you data group wise you have to use `having` instead of `where` and use aggregate functions like `sum()` to see if all columns apply to your condition.

```
select Incident_ID
from tbl_Investigation_Review 
group by Incident_ID
having sum(case when Status <> 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The `having` clause checks if there is no other `status` for your incidents.

Sicne you want only `approved` incidents you don't have to add that to your query output of your  `select`.